# Actionscript 3- How to create User Accounts, sign-ins, and admin accounts!(possibly with an API)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, web, user-accounts

Hey, How would you, in **actionscript 3** make a way to create, log-in, sign-out, etc. of **user accounts**? I'm mostly looking for an **API** i can use and if there is, how would I use it?

Alternatively, if there is no way to do it in AS3 as that is a longshot, how could I do it in **html** using **dreamweaver**?

FYI: this is for a website.

thanks for your response,
   -Custard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating user accounts and authenticating them are done at the server side. Actionscript, Javascript, HTML etc are client side languages to define the user interface. You create a signin/signup form using flash/html and post the user-entered data to a server side script (php/asp/jsp or whatever) that handles creating user accounts and/or authenticating them.

Google [actionscript login form](http://www.google.com/search?q=actionscript+login+form) or [html login form](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+login+form) for tutorials on how to design a login form using these technologies - there are tons of them out there.